# next line thingy doesn't work when used proper syntax

Tags: python-3.x, file, io, python-aiofiles

```
f.write(str(Path))
f.write("\n")
f.write(str(Monthly))
```

path is a string but Monthly is date. I can Insert all in a text file but I am not getting the desired output:

The output that I wish should be

```
D:\python
2021-04-08
```

But the output that I get is

```
D:\python
               <---causing error is this gap 
2021-04-08
```

The extra line after the path is causing problems.

Answer (score 0):

You literally used two newlines that caused the blank space. You may remove any of them to fix the issue for getting the desired output.

```py
f.write(str(Path))
f.write("\n")
f.write(str(Monthly))
```

Comment: That was typo 
Write function will give error as they are two args